# How to load objects dynamically to a query using LINQ expressions?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a function to include objects dynamically to a query.

The intention is to use like

```
empresa.Get(x => x.Employees);
```

or

```
empresa.Get(x => x.Employees, x => x.Department);
```

but when I try this, I receive this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type Expression<Func<EmpresaModel, object>>[] because its not a delegate type.

the function I write follow

```
public IQueryable<EmpresaModel> Get(params Expression<Func<EmpresaModel, object>>[] includes)
{
    var query = _conexao.Set<EmpresaModel>();

    foreach (var property in includes)
    {
        query.Include(property);
    }

    return query;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This compiles and runs without errors for me. Are you sure the error is in the source you gave?

Comment: Does not your code even compiling?

Comment: No, it does not compile. The IDE points to the same line of empresa.Get(x => x.Employees);

Comment: is this EF 6 or EF Core?

Comment: Hi. It is EF 6.